# How safe the neighborhood around the Leonardo Hotel in east Jerusalem?

Tags: israel, jerusalem

Have there been news reports in the past few months of stone throwing, knife attacks and the like along the route from Mea Sharim to the Leonardo Hotel at 9 Saint George Street, 97200 in east Jerusalem: http://www.leonardo-hotels.com/israel-hotels/jerusalem-hotels. (It seems there are two hotels with this name, so the address is important. I am considering staying there because it has a pool and is not as expensive as some other hotels.)

If so, are there more such incidents near that hotel during the day and through the early evening as compared to near the King David Hotel or the Inbal or in the German Colony?

Comment: @pnuts Would a prudent visitor to Israel walk to and near the hotel during the day and through the early evening?  How might the safety of doing so compare to walking around near the King David Hotel or the Inbal or the German Colony?

Comment: Have you viewed the [Dept of State's briefing?](https://www.osac.gov/pages/ContentReportDetails.aspx?cid=15239)

Comment: IMHO safety is more neighbourhood- than hotel-dependent. Moreover it is somewhat ludicrous to expect us to know all the hotels in Jerusalem, hence naming them one by one doesn't really add any information. You might want to rephrase your question using neighbourhoods rather than hotel names. :)

Comment: @JoErNanO I hope the address and link will identify the neighborhood.  I am not familiar with the names or boundaries of the neighborhoods in Jerusalem. I did not mean to be ludicrous.